# What construct is “zu tun ist”?

Tags: sentence-structure, grammar-identification

Many German sentences end with the construct ***zu tun ist***, for example:

> Er weiß, was zu tun ist.

Why do I need the *ist* at the end of the sentence? Why can I not just say the following?

> Er weiß, was zu tun.

Also, what grammatical construct is it?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

"Ist" is the verb (more precisely, the *finite* verb) of the subordinate clause. Because it is a subordinate clause, the verb has to be at the end.

> Es **ist** zu tun. "It has to be done."
>
> Er weiß, was zu tun **ist**. "He knows what has to be done".

Unlike in the English sentence "He knows what to do" in German a verb is needed in the subordinate clause.

Comment: +1 for "He knows what has to be done", great way to translate the grammatical constructs to English.

Comment: Also "Er weiß, was zu tun." equals "He knows what to be done."

Comment: @Alex or RHa - How would you say just "He knows what to do"?

Comment: In *»Er weis, was zu tun«* there also is a verb at the end of the sentence (*tun*). You also could write: *»"Tun" is the verb of the subordinate clause. Because it is a subordinate clause, the verb has to be at the end.«*

Comment: *Ist* is the *finite* verb, *tun* is not. I've edited my answer.

Comment: @BruceWayne Well, I'm just a layman and I'm not sure, but I guess I'd just use the OP's sentence "Er weiß, was zu tun ist." And when I'd translate it back into English I'd write "He knows what IS to be done." :-/

Answer (score 4):

Die naheliegende Antwort wäre wohl, dass ein Satz im Deutschen, um als vollständig zu gelten, in aller Regel in Verb braucht. Das gilt auch für einen Nebensatz wie dein "was zu tun ist".

Jedoch gibt es natürlich Ausnahmen von dieser Regel (wie überhaupt die Regeln einer Sprache ja nur die Ausnahmen von den Ausnahmen sind).

In dichterischer Sprache könntest du durchaus sagen:

> Er weiß, was zu tun.

Umso mehr, wenn du in Versen sprichst, also mit einem bestimmten Rhythmus:

> Lang rätselt' er, lang grübelt' er. Nun weiß er, was zu tun:
>
> Er fängt, er rupft, zerlegt und wirft in einen Suppentopf das Huhn.

Aber im Alltag wäre es dann doch:

> Er weiß, was zu tun ist.
>
> Sie weiß, wie sie Sätze zu bilden hat.
>
> Er weiß, wie er sich zu benehmen hat.

Aber:

> Er weiß sich zu benehmen.
>
> Sie weiß Sätze zu bilden.

Comment: Die Prämisse, der Nebensatz »..., was zu tun« enthielte kein Verb, ist schlichtweg falsch. Oder ist »tun« kein Verb? (*»Was **tut** ihr da?« »Wir **tun** hier nur unseren Job.«*) Vor 100 bis 200 war es sogar ganz normal, Sätze wie *»Er weiß, was zu tun«* zu schreiben. Die Erzählungen von E.T.A. Hoffmann sind voll von solchen Sätzen.

Comment: When the question was in English, then the answer should also be in English.

Comment: "in aller Regel in Verb braucht." is the "in verb" correct?

Answer (score 0):

There is a slight difference between "was zu tun," and "was zu tun ist."

"Was zu tun" is a perfectly good phrase that means approximately, "what to do."

"Was zu tun *ist*," is a more emphatic construction with the connotations of "what *is* to be done," or "what *should* be done."